# What is the difference between these 2 php variables that cause different json output?

Tags: php, json

The first one is;

```
$emailAddress = ['email_addr' => test@gmail.com ];
```

The second one is

```
$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => test@gmail.com ];
```

For the first one, when I run `echo json_encode($emailAddress);`, I get

```
{
    email_addr: "test@gmail.com"
}
```

For the second, when I run `echo json_encode($emailAddress);`, I get

```
[
  - {
         email_addr: "test@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

What is the difference between the 2 variables that cause the different json output?

Comment: `[]` See that part in the second declaration ?

Comment: @Rizier123, thanks. Does that make the variable an array?

Comment: May I ask why the 3 negative votes? What is wrong with the question? Should I delete it? Can someone explain so that I can improve or delete the question?

Comment: Yes, it will add an array element. And you will add `['email_addr' => test@gmail.com ]` as array element

Comment: Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: @user768421 There are no stupid questions, there are only stupid people...and they can vote.

Comment: @Shailendra Sharma, thank you very much for making me feel not so stupid. It would be better if those who downvoted at least explain why they find the question stupid so that I can ask more intelligently in future.

Comment: Don't be upset, you question doesn't have to be "stupid" to be downvoted. It can be downvoted because it has been asked a lot of times, because it denotes the asking user did not even googled it, because it should be asked in another kind of page... many reasons. But yes, it would be cool if people reasoned why they downvoted it. It is actually a recomended behaviour every time you downvote a question.

Comment: @Amarnasan, thanks. I have chosen your answer as the answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a hash of one element.

The second one is an array with one element being a hash of one element

Actually the second one can be explained as:

> $emailAdress is an array, and I'm adding one element that happens to
>   be a hash of one element.

and you'll read it more properly if you write it like if it is a different operator:

```
$emailAddress  []=  ['email_addr' => test@gmail.com ];
```

instead of

```
$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => test@gmail.com ];
```

Just the way you add a string to another string using the "." operand

```
$foo .= "text";
```

you can add an element to an array using the " [] " operand

```
$foo []= "bar";
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is JSON string.

The second one is JSON array with one element **(JSON string)**